# simular un click en un select al momento de cargar la pagina

Tags: javascript

Quiero simular un click en un elemento select que al momento de cargar la pagina ya esten las imagenes cargadas, ya que en este momento me carga el select con los grupos pero necesito que este seleccionado por defecto para que al abrir la pagina ya esten cargadas las imagenes. gracias dejo el codigo

```
$(nombreProdu());
function nombreProdu(busquedaProdu){
    $.ajax({
        url:'admin/phpadmin/selectProductos.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'html',
        data : {busquedaProdu: busquedaProdu},
    }) 
    .done(function(result){
        $("#cbx_carrito").html(result);
    })
}

// carga las imagenes al abrir la pagina
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cbx_carrito').click(function(){
        var valor = $('#cbx_carrito').val();
        if (valor != null) {
            $('#cbx_carrito').val('1').click(); 
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){     
    $("#cbx_carrito").change(function () {
        $("#cbx_carrito option:selected").each(function () {
            id_producto = $(this).val();
            $.get("php/carritoproductos.php", { id_producto: id_producto }, function(data){
                $("#cargaCarrito").html(data);
            });            
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un trigger con jquery, la sintaxis sería así:

```
    if (valor != null) {
        $('#cbx_carrito').val('1');
        $('#cbx_carrito').trigger("change"); 
    }
```

Puse change, pero si quieres click solo cambialo por "click".

Otra cosa, lo correcto sería solo tener un `$(document).ready` para que el código se ejecute correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

te voy a dejar 2 opciones mira cual te puede servir

**1. función por referencia**

*1.1.* se crean primero las funciones

```
function clickcar(){
        var valor = $('#cbx_carrito').val();
        if (valor != null) {
            $('#cbx_carrito').val('1').click(); 
        }
    }
function changecar() {
        $("#cbx_carrito option:selected").each(function () {
            id_producto = $(this).val();
            $.get("php/carritoproductos.php", { id_producto: id_producto }, function(data){
                $("#cargaCarrito").html(data);
            });            
        });
    }
```

*1.2.* se asignan a los eventos y se llaman

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cbx_carrito').click(clickcar);
    $("#cbx_carrito").change(changecar);
    clickcar();
    changecar();
});
```

**2. trigguer**

*2.1.* solo debes lanzar el evento

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cbx_carrito').click(function(){
        var valor = $('#cbx_carrito').val();
        if (valor != null) {
            $('#cbx_carrito').val('1').click(); 
        }
    });
    $("#cbx_carrito").change(function () {
        $("#cbx_carrito option:selected").each(function () {
            id_producto = $(this).val();
            $.get("php/carritoproductos.php", { id_producto: id_producto }, function(data){
                $("#cargaCarrito").html(data);
            });            
        });
    });
$("#cbx_carrito").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que tengo un select dinamico con ajax, funciona correctamente lo que necesita es que cuando abriera la pagina, cargara la imagenes que contenga la opcion del select; de la opcion seleccionada. ya que al momento de abrir la pagina cargaba la opcion pero sin las imagenes hasta que le hiciera click en el select, resumido que simulara el click en el select y cargue las imagnes de la opcion seleccionada. Les dejo el codigo espero les sirva a alguien.

```
$(nombreProdu());
function nombreProdu(busquedaProdu)
{
  $.ajax({
    url:'admin/phpadmin/selectProductos.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'html',
    data : {busquedaProdu: busquedaProdu},
  })

  .done(function(result){
    $("#cbx_carrito").html(result);//lo que se imprime en la pagina
    $('#cbx_carrito').val('1').trigger('change');// cambia al valor 1, muestra y carga las imagenes cuando abre la pagina.
  })
}



$(document).ready(function(){ // funcion de traer las imagenes segun la opcion seleccionada.
                $("#cbx_carrito").change(function () {
                    $("#cbx_carrito option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_producto = $(this).val();
                        $.get("php/carritoproductos.php", { id_producto: id_producto }, function(data){
                            $("#cargaCarrito").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });
```